# Loading & Selecting audio files into Audio Units

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to build a Render Callback function that will load a variety of short sound files, and (according to my custom logic) put them in my mixer Unit's iOData audioBufferList.  How do I load an aif or caf file into the program, and appropriately import its samples into the ioData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Extended Audio File Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html), particularly "ExtAudioFileOpenURL" and "ExtAudioFileRead".  Remember not to do anything too time consuming in the render callback (e.g. opening a file may be considered time consuming, allocating memory definitely is).

Comment: Right, so I can use the Audio File Services to load my audio files in ViewDidLoad:, but what about the second part of my question?  Would I use ExtAudioFileRead, and point the iOData at the Render callback's ioData object?

Comment: @DanF Yes, e.g.:
`OSStatus renderCallback(..., AudioBufferList *ioData) {  ...; UInt32 numFrames = inNumberFrames;
ExtAudioFileRef audioFile = // Your file ref previously opened with ExtAudioFileOpenURL
OSStatus result = ExtAudioFileRead(audioFile, &numFrames, ioData);
// Check for error
// numFrames actually read may be less than request (e.g. if EOF) }`